# How do ISVs login to customer orgs after they have been granted access?

Tags: app-development

For a while now you have been able to grant administrator access to apps you have installed for support purposes.

A customer has granted me access but as an ISV I cannot see how to get into a customers org from either the org where the managed package is developed for the LMO org. I haven't found any useful documentation around this on DeveloperForce.

Any help from ISVs appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you were granted the login? and not the customer administrator, or SF rep?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Providing the customer has gone into Grant Login Access and selected access to your app and not Salesforce.com Support (as that is for Salesforce only).

[image]

Then in your LMO, you should see a Subscribers tab.

[image]

Which looks like this...

[image]

Just enter your customers name, click the entry and it should bring up a summary page with some licensing details on it etc. There should be a related list with users from that organisation that have granted login. Click Login next to the desired user.

Here are some useful links...

- [Supporting Your Subscribers](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=packaging_user_support.htm&language=en_USa)
- [Logging in to Subscriber Organizations](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=lma_logging_in_to_sub_org.htm&language=en_US)

Comment: Back when this feature was in beta you had to sign a contract addendum about use of it being restricted to employees and other reasonable restrictions. I suspect if you don't see this in your org you need to contact SFDC to have it enabled.

Comment: I do not see a list of users although I know they have granted access to us. Why would this be?