# Not receiving all Apex Exception emails for Managed Package

Tags: apex, managed-package, email, exception

We have a Managed Package deployed on several dozen orgs, and appear to be missing a lot of Apex Exception emails.

We do receive a number of such emails on a regular basis (so we know it's working sometimes) but find that *most* of the time when debugging an issue in a customers org, Apex Exception emails do not appear to be arriving in our Mailbox.

Within the org we receive the exception page along with the text

```
"An unexpected error has occurred. Your solution provider has been notified. (name of our package)"
```

However 9 times out of 10, no email is received within our org. (Occasionally one does make it through, but it's extremely rare).

We've checked spam folders and looked at mail server logs, and cannot find any trace of them.

Has anybody had this problem and been able to resolve?

Alternatively, is there another/easier way to view a stack trace when an exception is generated in a customers org within a managed package?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We did notice this as well, however we tend to now use Subscriber support to login and reproduce the issue. If you login via Subscriber support you can see the stack traces and full debug information for you packages. Take a look at the answer to this [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/3797/how-do-isvs-login-to-customer-orgs-after-they-have-been-granted-access/3799#3799) for more information about the Subscriber Support feature, it's a must for an ISV!

[image]

Comment: It's worth noting that those emails are *never* generated for sandbox environments, despite the message saying they are.