# Error email from Packages are not delivered reliably

Tags: managed-package, appexchange, error-messages, isv

To better reproduce and understand errors of our managed package that only occurr in customer orgs we cannot only rely on Subscriber support or logging. This is for multiple reasons, hard to repeat batch processes, Log files to big to yield errors and other platform specifics are some of them.

As an extra safety net we started to receive and store all error messages sent out by our package but in 9 out of 10 errors in a customer org no error email is sent out. It really looks randomly. We first thought only Async processes don't sent out email, but they sometimes do.

*Is there any authorative answer when such emails are sent and when not? I know this is a **duplicate** of [Not receiving all Apex Exception emails for Managed Package](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4083/not-receiving-all-apex-exception-emails-for-managed-package) but I can't put a bounty on somebody elses question.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Salesforce support told me (in Case 14051137) the following:

> The framework that sends email notifications when unhandled exceptions
>   occur implements a **complex suppression logic** to avoid being too noisy.
>   In a nutshell its logic is explained at
>   https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_exception_definition.htm.
>
> However the note on async jobs is incorrect, as **same behaviour** is
>   experienced i**n both sync and async** jobs. Basically notification of
>   unhandled exceptions is handled by the gack framework that implements
>   a complex suppression logic, and makes receiving these
>   non-deterministic. Best approach is to implement try and catch that
>   will cover all "catchable" events (it will not include the
>   "uncatchable" ones such as hitting governor limits or internal server
>   errors)
>
> Unfortunately the suppression logic uses rate limits and cache that
>   make **email notification non-deterministic from a developer's point of
>   view**, but the decision to suppress notification is always performed
>   according to its logic.
>
> Also as per the internal discussion, it was suggested internally that
>   **this framework should be replaced** with a different mechanism that
>   could stream all the errors and persist them into a repository.
>   Unfortunately, there is **no ETA** for the same as of now for the same.
>
> As a next step we would encourage you to **support the same by raising
>   an IDEA** at our portal for "enhanced exception notification without
>   any suppression". So that we can get this implemented accordingly.

Please vote for the **[Idea "Enhanced exception notification without any suppression to package owner"](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000PTxLQAW)** that I submitted as a follow-up.

Comment: This is good to know. Thanks for clarification. Hopefully more folks vote for the idea to improve this.