# Capture Stack Trace in Managed Package

Tags: apex, managed-package, login-errors

Can you capture and store stack trace information in a managed package? [This page](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000GnJKAA0) says that the idea was delivered, but that's not what I'm seeing.

The same code stores this stack trace in the unmanaged version:

```
 Stack Trace:
    Class.PMT_PaymentCreator.<init>: line 107, column 1
    Class.PMT_Payment_TDTM.run: line 48, column 1
    Class.TDTM_TriggerHandler.runClass: line 118, column 1
    Class.TDTM_TriggerHandler.run: line 68, column 1
    Trigger.TDTM_Opportunity: line 34, column 1
```

And this one in the managed one:

```
 Stack Trace:
   (npsp)
```

I'm using the **getStackTraceString** method from the Exception class.

Comment: It takes a support request to get detailed logging information turned on for a managed package. This is pure speculation, but perhaps this feature also requires enabling by Salesforce support?

Answer (score 9):

You need to be an [ISV](http://www.salesforce.com/isvforce/overview/) and [login to the customers org using Subscriber support](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/3797/how-do-isvs-login-to-customer-orgs-after-they-have-been-granted-access) to see any logging from the managed package, including the stack trace.

See comments on [Capturing process information with Apex](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/8295/102)

Comment: Still testing the issue. A deeper rabbit hole that you'd think. I'll mark your answer as correct as soon as I verify it. We are definitely an ISV (Salesforce.com Foundation), but for now I'm just testing a beta of the new version of our package (the Nonprofit Starter Pack) in a dev org. Got access to the list of Subscribers in the LMA and found the org where I installed the beta. However the package is not listed as one of those belonging to the Foundation...Maybe it's not signed because it's a beta?

Comment: This does not work in this case, as we are still working with the beta version, which is not identified as being owned by us. Not sure if it will work when we have a production release...

Comment: I'd previously raised the idea [Expose logging from a Beta managed package in the deployed org](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000gkuYAAQ) around this. In @ca_peterson's answer he reports that beta packages work with the subscribers tab, but I've never had the chance to try it.

Comment: I just commented below. Subscribers tab did not work for me on beta package...

Comment: We have the error stack traces stored into a custom object, but even using the subscribers tab log in doesn't unmask the stacktrace; just says `(namespace)`. So it seems the masking occurs before even saving it. So this method won't get you historical stacktraces.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the ISV subscribers console method posted by Daniel backline support is technically able to "unmask debug logs" for a managed namespace **temporarily** which will expose this info. You'll need consent from the package author (if it's not you) to make this happen.

Comment: This is good to know. This would be a partial solution to Ideas: [Expose logging from a Beta managed package in the deployed org](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000gkuYAAQ)

Comment: The subscribers tab worked on beta packages last I checked. By far the best solution to that idea imo

Comment: Ah, OK. Thinks may have moved on in the 2 years since that Idea was raised.

Comment: Any idea if this works for error information already stored? We have implemented error handling in our package that will store error information in the database. I'd be great if the "masking" of stack traces happened at runtime. That is, that the stack trace was stored regardless, but that it's shown only if the unmasking of debug logs is enabled.

Comment: @ceiroa no way of enabling this retroactively that I know of. However unhandled exceptions (that make it to the top of the stack) do get the stack trace emailed to the package author (although this doesn't work for sandboxes for some reason)

Comment: The problem is that we tried to be smart. We set a savepoint, catch the exception, do the rollback, and log the exception. This works great in unmanaged code but now we are stack without stack trace in the database or in emails.

Comment: Subscribers tab did not work for me on beta package. Which would be expected, as the package is not listed as owned by our organization in the org where it is installed.

Comment: That's odd. It's worked for me recently, and I have no idea why it might be different for you. Too bad there's no real way to debug this outside of SFDC support.

Comment: @ceiroa nearly identical situation here to what you've described. Did you manage to 
come up with a solution?

Comment: No permanent solution @Aequitas. As mentioned above, the log masking can be only temporarily disabled for a specific org throw Salesforce's support. It can't be done permanently or in a large scale, AFAIK.